# how I can select view in 3d tikz? and how I can change view?

Tags: tikz-pgf

In some example when they want to chose view use below , how? how numbers selected? if i want change view how it is possible?

```
[x={(0.866cm,0.5cm)}, y={(0.866cm,0.5cm)}, z={(0cm,1cm)}, scale=1]
```

Comment: Except for a few missing minus signs, this is known as isomorphic view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The axes specified by the OP corresponds to a radius of 2/\sqrt{3} rather than one, but proportionately one can use:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{135}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=1.1547]
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: 3d axes]