# Using pst-3dplot together with viewpoint

Tags: pstricks, pst-3dplot

I would like to change the viewpoint in the following picture:

```
\documentclass[pstricks, border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(4,4)
    \psset{viewpoint=1 1 1}
    \pstThreeDCoor[xMin=-0.2,xMax=4,yMin=-0.2,yMax=4, zMin=-0.2,zMax=4]
    {\psset{fillcolor=blue,fillstyle=solid, linewidth=0.5pt}
    \pstThreeDSquare(0,0,0)(3,0,0)(0,3,0)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: bsp]

But this way `viewpoint` has no effect.

Comment: Maybe an alternative solution with `tdplotsetmaincoords` [how I can select view in 3d tikz? and how I can change view?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/267488/124842)

Comment: `pst-3dplot` is for a _parallel_ view of 3d objects. And for this kind of view you need only Alpha and Beta

Comment: @Herbert I would like to have a centre projection. I now tried it with ps3-solides3d. see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384910/pst-solides3d-draw-squares-between-others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `viewpoint` key in `pst-3dplot`. This key is defined in `pst-solides3d`. Instead, `pst-3dplot` uses `Alpha` (rotation of the horizontal axes around the vertical axis;default: 45) and `Beta` (vertical rotation angle, default: 30).

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[svgnames, border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot, pst-solides3d}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}
    % \psset{viewpoint=1 3 1}
    \psset{Alpha =140, Beta =40}
    \psset{fillcolor=LightSteelBlue!60!Gainsboro!30!, fillstyle=solid, linewidth=0.5pt}
    \pstThreeDCoor[xMin=-0.2,xMax=4,yMin=-0.2,yMax=4, zMin=-0.2,zMax=4]
    \pstThreeDSquare(0,0,0)(3,0,0)(0,3,0)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is no need to put `\pstThreeDSquare` in braces

Comment: @Herbert: You're perfectly right. It was taken for the O.P.'s code, but I don't know why I didn't change that…

Comment: no, in the original post the `{ .... }`  where around _two_  lines

Comment: Yes, and I removed one superfluous line without removing the braces.