# pst-solides3d: Draw squares between others

Tags: pstricks, pst-solides3d

In order to create a gif I did the following:

```
\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\viewpoint}{25 15 5}
\newcommand{\axis}{\axesIIID(0,0,0)(4.5,4,4)}
\psset{unit=1}
\psset{viewpoint=\viewpoint}
\psset{action=draw*,incolor=green!20!white, linewidth=0.5pt}

\multido{\i=1+2}{3}{
\begin{pspicture}(-5.3,-2.5)(7,8)
 \axis
 \multido{\r=0+1.5}{3}{
 \psSolid[object=face, base=3 3 3 0 0 0 0 3](0,0,\r)}
 \multido{\r=0.75+1.5}{2}{
 \psSolid[object=face, base=3 3 3 0 0 0 0 3](0,0,\r)}
 \psset{incolor=red}
 \multido{\r=0.375+0.75}{\i}{
 \psSolid[object=face, base=3 3 3 0 0 0 0 3](0,0,\r)}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Is it possible to draw the green squares first and then draw the red between them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a question of when you draw the planes. It can also be done with `pst-3dplot`:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}
\psset{viewpoint=25 15 5, linewidth=0.5pt}

\multido{\i=2+2}{4}{%
  \begin{pspicture}(-5.3,-2.5)(7,8)
    \axesIIID(0,0,0)(4.5,4,4)
    \multido{\r=0.0+-0.375,\iA=0+1}{9}{%
      \ifodd\iA
        \ifnum\iA<\i
          \psSolid[object=plan,definition=equation,
            fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red,
            args={[0 0 1 \r]},base=-1.5 1.5 -1.5 1.5]
        \fi
      \else
        \psSolid[object=plan,definition=equation,
          fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green!20!white,
          args={[0 0 1 \r]},base=-1.5 1.5 -1.5 1.5]
      \fi}
    \end{pspicture}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]